# how i can run if else statement with radio button?

Tags: java, android, radio-button

How can I run the correct if else statement on RadioButton?

I have no idea what is the correct coding for this part

> onRadioButtonClicked.selected

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(View v) {
  if onRadioButtonClicked.selected{
   //insert data to sql 
  } else {
   //insert data to sql 
  }
 }
}
```

**Please correct my code above**

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        switch(view.getId()) {

        case R.id.radioButtonA:
            if (checked)            
               String A= intent.getStringExtra("A");
            break;
        case R.id.radioButtonA:
            if (checked)
               String B= intent.getStringExtra("B");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. In the below code, your switch case has the same button as a case twice. That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
radioButtonA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChange);
radioButtonB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChange);

OnCheckedChangedListener checkedChange = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       if(isChecked){
           switch(buttonView.getId()){
               case R.id.radioButtonA:          
                   String A= intent.getStringExtra("A");
               break;
               case R.id.radioButtonB:
                   String B= intent.getStringExtra("B");
               break;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Then

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (onRadioButtonClicked.isChecked()){
            //insert data to sql 
        } 
        else {
           //insert data to sql 
        }
    }
});
```

**NOTE** Your code is quite messed up. I am just giving you a right track. You might have to make other changes such as change `radioButtonA` and `radioButtonB` as per the name you are using in your code. Also, this might not be the only one change required.